# . I spend most of my money (on) shopping. - which one is right?

Tags: word-usage

I know I can say:

> 1. I spend most of my time studying at a coffee shop.

then how about this?

> 2. I spend most of my money shopping.

I feel the better one is this:

> 3. I spend most of my money on shopping.

Which one is right?

Comment: I think both 2 and 3 is grammatically correct however,  using "~ sth doing sth" is often used with an explanation about the "doing". If you want to imply a general idea I think the preposition ( using a preposition )on/in/at is more sensible.

Answer (score 1):

As the saying goes: When in Rome do as the Romans do.

Maybe, you don't spend on shopping in AE, but I think you can spend on shopping in BE. In BE, the word shopping implies not only the activity of buying things but also the things you have bought from shops/stores.

Per Brian Hitchcock's answer, you can say "spend money on purchases".
However, in BE, you can use either shopping or purchases in these sentences.

Answer (score 0):

You spend your time **on** shopping. During that time, you spend money. So your spend your money [while] shopping.  But when you spend it, you spend it **on** the items you purchase.  You do not spend it **on** shopping.

To put it another way, you do not spend *to go shopping (except time and gas)*, you *go shopping*, and while there, spend money on purchases.